ShapeFile Server
Are WFS-T a good way to serve big and multiple shapefile in WebGis? Are they perfoming?
I'm using GeoServer.
I need to add, remove and modify ShapeFiles whenever I want.
Please some advise to structure a ShapeFile Server for a WebGis in 2024, thanks

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
